# Is there an algorithm to remap every Int32?

Tags: algorithms, encryption

I'm making a web application that can generate unique unsigned Int32 post IDs for posts. Normally I would just make it auto-increment from `0`.

But I don't want the user to "guess" what's the next ID will be from their own post ID. So I would like the sequence to be random. Let's say the very first post has the ID of `9681034`, then `106871123`, `681021`, `3006477106`...

Basically I want each UInt32 has its own unique map of another UInt32 with no obvious patterns.

```
f(0) = 9681034
f(1) = 106871123
f(2) = 681021
f(3) = 3006477106
...
f(4294967295) = 1627792604
```

Also it would be even better if I could provide a key to a generator function, and then the generator function could give me two functions that for mapping and unmapping the sequence.

```
gen(42) = [f, f']
```

Let's say the example above was generated by this generator, and the `f'()` can unmap the sequence for me

```
f'(f(0)) = 0
f'(f(1)) = 1
f'(f(2)) = 2
f'(f(3)) = 3
...
f'(f(4294967295)) = 4294967295
```

When I provide another key, the sequence changes completely.

---

Sorry I'm very new to CS and algorithm. Is there a known algorithm for this kind of mapping? What is it called? If not, how could I achieve it?

Comment: Have a look at (strong) pseudorandom permutations (and block ciphers). Essentially they are keyed functions that can be computed and inverted efficiently but are indistinguishable from random permutations to any polynomial-time adversary.

Comment: Another option is to use asymmetric encryption with a secret $s$ and public $p$ key pair.  Then if you do $s(x)$ for any message $x$, you will be able to extract it using $p(s(x))$.   The ID of post $x$ is the $s(x)$.

Comment: What you're looking for is a [pseudorandom permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_permutation) of the integers in the range `0..MAX_INT`. If you want the sequence to be unpredictable by attackers then you want a cryptographically pseudorandom permutation.

Comment: A Feistel network is a good way to turn a non-invertible function into a permutation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12996028/10872945) to a loosely related question may be interesting to You.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a cryptography-proof solution, add a 32 bits number, then scramble the bits. This is easy to invert.

Comment: The thing with this method is, the numbers with similar binary codes also yield similar result. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Instead of xoring, you can add a constant and ignore overflow. For the inversion, subtract and ignore undeflow. (I updated my post.)

Answer (score 1):

Take the [Speck cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speck_%28cipher%29) 32-bit block size variant, the key size is not important for you therefore select any of the 64,72, or 96-bit versions. The steps

1. select a uniform random key $k$ and store it.
2. keep a counter $counter = 0$
3. When need a new ID, encrypt the $counter$ with the key

$$ID = Speck32_k(counter) $$

4. Increment $counter$

Repeat the steps 3 and 4 for when a new ID is required.

---

A little theory to explain why this is a permutation.

Speck like AES is a block cipher and block cipher are synonym for pseudo-random permutation. A block cipher must be reversible for the decryption therefore it is a permutation. And, sometimes we also say that a block cipher is a family of permutations that are selected/determined by the key from all possible permutations from $2^{32}$ to $2^{32}$.

If you keep the same key, you have selected one of the permutations of the family, and asking from 0 to $2^{32}-1$ you get the permuted values.